# Looking for an ultra wide modulation bandwidth, ultra linear VCO

Tags: oscillator, vco

I'm searching for a VCO in the 200-500 MHz area with 60 MHz modulation bandwidth which maintains 2% linearity (ideally better) in its tuning range. Would also prefer it to also hold 2% or better variation in frequency over 20-60 degrees C. I'm willing to compromise on phase noise and spurs. Square wave output is just fine. The only such devices I know of are current controlled multivibrators with a transconductance amp on the control line, but I've not yet found a chip which implements such a thing. There's also using a ring oscillator and current starving it... but again I haven't found a chip that implements this outside of it being a piece of a much larger IC.

Comment: Ultra this and ultra that ... can you put any actual numbers to your requirements? Most people doing this kind of work today would simply synthesize the signal in the digital domain. Is there some reason you're avoiding this approach?

Comment: Not possible to have ultra-linear 2:1 VCO in this band without great  compromises on phase noise distortion, temp sensitivity, sensitivity to load, spurious outputs, . Tuning Sensitivity increases amplify phase noise significantly. So you must tune over a narrow GHz Range and down convert or some other method of synthesis.

Comment: I've added numbers. Sorry about that!

Comment: I am, as I have said, willing to compromise severely on phase noise. I've added that I'm willing to compromise on spurs as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware of, there are no linear VCOs with a continuous tuning range of over an octave in the 200-500MHz range. I would instead use an VCO in the lower GHz range, that offers you a tuning range of the 300MHz you need and mix it down using a fixed oscillator that is 200MHz lower/higher than your VCO. This way will not be the lowest phase noise, but you should get a quite decent linearity and high tuning bandwidth (in the order of 10-50MHz). Suitable devices can be found from Hittite (now Analog), eg the HMC384/385/386 family.